# Get data in array through form

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am not getting data in my array when i submit the form I am using AJax then .

```
$post['FirstName'] = $_POST['FirstName'];  //not getting value in array from form
$newArray = array(); // initialize new array
$i = 0;
foreach ($post as $key => $value) {
$newArray[$i]['Attribute'] = $key;
$newArray[$i]['Value'] = $value;
$i++;
}

$data_string =  json_encode($newArray);
```

[image: HERE IS THE IMAGE]

[AJAX Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTR41.png)

Comment: Can you `var_dump($newArray)` after foreach?

Comment: Why the `$post['FirstName'] = $_POST['FirstName']` part ? You can loop through `$_POST` no ? Try to `var_dump($post)` before the loop to be sure that you have something

Comment: array(5) {
  ["FirstName"]=>
  NULL
  ["EmailAddress"]=>
  NULL
  ["LastName"]=>
  NULL
  ["Phone"]=>
  NULL
  ["SearchBy"]=>
  NULL
}
[{"Attribute":"FirstName","Value":null},{"Attribute":"EmailAddress","Value":null},{"Attribute":"LastName","Value":null},{"Attribute":"Phone","Value":null},{"Attribute":"SearchBy","Value":null}]

Comment: share your ajax request code in your question plz

Comment: Ajax call screenshot has been added.

Comment: @devpro have you checked?

Comment: `console.log(postvalues)` use this before ajax request and share the result